# Script not working with crontab but working when launching it normally

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cron-task

this is my first question on SO, otherwise I generally find what I need.

So here we go, here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/laxa/Teeworlds_servers/scripts
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
kill `ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep "/home/laxa/Teeworlds_servers/" | awk ' { print $2 } '`
```

and here is my crontab test :

```
48 23 * * * /home/laxa/Teeworlds_servers/scripts/restart_server.sh > /home/laxa/log.txt 2>&1
```

So, when I use the script in a bash shell with putty, the script gets executed fine and does it's job.
But when it's executed by the crontab, after some debug, it fails on the kill command.
I tried to set manually the PATH cause it was a big wrong.
Another friend told me to try to debug it, but apparently the script dies directly.

So I am quite blocked now, if someone has an idea or a solution, I would really welcome it.
Thanks.

Comment: When it fails on the `kill`, do you get any error messages? Or can you catch its exit code?

Comment: I don't have any error message. Don't know how to catch exit code.

Comment: Are you sure then that if fails on the `kill`? Because you're redirecting STDERR to your log file, and you should see some kind of error message there, right?

Comment: I am absolutely sure.

Comment: if your log file is created correctly, try adding the content of the command substitution just before the kill line to see its output: `ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep "/home/laxa/Teeworlds_servers/" | awk ' { print $2 } '`

Comment: Does your script run correctly when prepended with an `env -i`?

Comment: Ok so, finally I founded that my line was working, but she was returning more processes than intended. And then I discovered that the script was killing himself, so thanks guys !

Comment: @laxa You should post an answer yourself and mark it as accepted. That's the best way to handle it when you solve your problem yourself. (Or, if you don't think your solution would help anybody else, you could delete the question. In this case I think your answer is pretty interesting and worth posting.)

Comment: Indeed, running a script under a prefix that matches what you are grepping for is going to be a problem. That's why you don't grep the output of `ps`. You use tools like `pgrep` and `pkill` that handle some of these problems for you (and let you specify processes more specifically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, finally I founded that my line was working, but she was returning more processes than intended. And then I discovered that the script was killing himself, so thanks guys !